# Getting FastifyError [Error]: fastify-plugin: fastify-static - expected '3.x' fastify version, '4.2.1' is installed error

Tags: fastify

I tried upgrading to fastify v4 and got this error:

```
FastifyError [Error]: fastify-plugin: fastify-static - expected '3.x' fastify version, '4.2.1' is installed
     at Object.checkVersion (/var/www/node_modules/fastify/lib/pluginUtils.js:118:11)
     at Object.registerPlugin (/var/www/node_modules/fastify/lib/pluginUtils.js:133:16)
     at Boot.override (/var/www/node_modules/fastify/lib/pluginOverride.js:28:57)
     at Plugin.exec (/var/www/node_modules/avvio/plugin.js:79:33)
     at Boot.loadPlugin (/var/www/node_modules/avvio/plugin.js:272:10)
     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
   code: 'FST_ERR_PLUGIN_VERSION_MISMATCH',
   statusCode: 500
 }
```

I tried adding `@fastify/static` dependency with version `6.4.0` but that didn't help. Any idea how can I fix this?

These are my current dependencies in the project that uses fastify v3:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@fastify/swagger": "^6.1.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "deepmerge": "^4.2.2",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "fastify": "^3.29.0",
    "fastify-decorators": "3.12.0",
    "http-status-codes": "2.2.0",
    "jwt-decode": "3.1.2",
    "node-mocks-http": "^1.11.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.16",
    "qs": "^6.10.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.7.0",
    "winston": "^3.7.2",
    "winston-daily-rotate-file": "^4.7.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@fastify/redis": "^5.0.0",
    "@tsconfig/node16-strictest-esm": "^1.0.2",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.27",
    "@types/qs": "^6.9.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.22.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.22.0",
    "eslint": "^8.17.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^17.0.0",
    "eslint-config-typescript": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-n": "^15.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.0.0",
    "jest": "^28.1.0",
    "prettier": "^2.6.2",
    "ts-jest": "^28.0.5",
    "typescript": "^4.6.4"
  }
```

I basically just updated fastify's version to 4.2.1 and gave it a try and got this error and also tried adding `@fastify/static` dependency as noted above and that did not fix this either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't updating @fastify/swagger. You need to update @fastify/swagger to v7.x to support Fastify v4.x.